# Leaflet LatLngBounds with simpler CRS & projection

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using Leaflet 0.7.7, latest stable release, and I'm using a custom CRS inherited from `L.CRS.Simple`.

**CRS:**

It is very similar to Simple CRS but with `c` set to `1` (in Simple, `c` is set to `-1`).

```js
L.CRS.XY = L.Util.extend({}, L.CRS.Simple, {
    code: 'XY',
    projection: L.Projection.LonLat,
    transformation: new L.Transformation(1, 0, 1, 0)
});
```

The goal of this CRS is to have a real `{x, y}` map system where `y` becomes higher when reaching the bottom of the map (like a bitmap).

**Code to test:**

```js
var southWest = L.latLng(133, 0);
var northEast = L.latLng(0, 170);
var bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

document._map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
document._map.fitBounds(bounds);
document._markers[68].setLatLng(bounds.getNorthEast());

console.info('southWest', southWest);
// L.LatLng {lat: 133, lng: 0}

console.info('northEast', northEast);
// L.LatLng {lat: 0, lng: 170}

console.info('bounds', bounds);
// L.LatLngBounds (
    _northEast: L.LatLng {lat: 133, lng: 170 }
    _southWest: L.LatLng {lat: 0, lng: 0 }
)
```

Actually, as I have a custom CRS, I think [these lines](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v0.7.7/src/geo/LatLngBounds.js#L32-L36) are the source of the problem because maximum and minimum values are not correct in a plane `{x, y}` system (even if I would prefer to use "Point" but I can only use "LatLng" objects :confused: ).

So actually, it seems it is obvious that this issue comes from my code, but actually I'd like to find a solution for this that wouldn't need me to switch to `L.CRS.Simple` in which `y` coordinates get higher on top of the map.

So what's the solution to use bounds with this simple custom projection?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

It sounds like Leaflet internally assumes that y points increase when going down (like in images), and it should be the opposite for latitude (i.e. decrease when going down), as the min, max, <= and >= comparisons are hard-coded.

So there is probably no possibility to make up a CRS that will give you a latitude in the same direction as the Y points. Except if you are ready to modify every function that compares latitudes within Leaflet library…

You may still be able to "manipulate" numbers like you wish, if you use an intermediate conversion function every time you have to provide coordinates, and the opposite when you have to read coordinates.

That would also give you the opportunity to revert the latitude (y) and longitude (x) order to be [x, y].

For example:

```js
function revertLat(x, y) {
  return [-y, x];
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/101/

---

Original answer:

Any reason for not directly customizing `L.LatLngBounds` as well, so that it fits your need?

First of all, if you do not exactly need southWest and northEast, but just *corners* for your bounds, you can use `L.LatLngBounds` as is. For instance, all Leaflet methods would keep working even if the corners are not exactly southWest and northEast: `map.fitBounds`, `L.imageOverlay` etc. should work fine.

Otherwise, you would have to customize many methods in `L.LatLngBounds` (extend, pad, contains, intersects) to revert the min / max and <= / >= comparisons.

Comment: The problem is that the L.LatLngBounds class considers that we're using classic a transformation class like this: L.Transformation(1, 0, -1, 0).
This is why the "computed" southWest and northEast bounds are incorrect. Actually, if I used L.latLng(0, -170); instead of L.latLng(0, 170); in my northEast var, it "would" work, but it doesn't because the projection used to match the bounds is incorrect...
 
Will I have to switch back to L.Projection.LonLat? :(

Comment: You have not answered to this question: do you really need "southWest" and "northEast"? Can you live with "northWest" and "southEast" instead? Or put more simply, can you just consider that your "North" is down, and "South" is up? Leaflet should work as is (let us know if it does not).

Comment: I am not forced to use southWest or northEast. I need an array of latlng that represent boundaries of my world, and it does not matter whether it's southWest or northWest. Actually, whatever order I use for the boundaries (southwest, northwest, etc.) the boundaries are incorrect and the fitBounds do not work.

Comment: For example if I use this : map.setMaxBounds([ [0, 0], [133, 170] ]); (first is northWest and second is southEast), it does not work. When navigating in the map, boundaries "force" me to navigate at the horizontal middle of the map, and can't go to north or south (but east and west boundaries are correct).

Comment: mmm bad news indeed. To avoid having to "correct" each and every Leaflet function that uses bounds, you may better try to find a way to use custom lat/lng. I will update the above answer.

Comment: I think I'm gonna need to use classic LonLat projection with the usual transformation that considers that Y coordinates decrease at the top and increase at the bottom of the map... Sick of this, it took me months to find a way to convert hundreds of markers/polylines/polygons from Mercator to classic X,Y format, now I have to update my script and refactor my code to fit to this bug... Quite sad :(
But I'll do it if I have no choice :(

Comment: Actually, it could be good if Leaflet could take care of transformations classes when creating/managing boundaries :/