# How can I match Leaflet co-ordinates to pixels in non-geographical map?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have an image that is 5617 * 3973 pixels. I want to use it as a leaflet map image overlay map.
I want to make it such that 1 pixel = 1 map unit (latlng). So this is what I did:

```
 var map = L.map('mapid', {
        crs: L.CRS.Simple,
        minZoom: -2, 
        maxZoom:0.5
}); 

var bounds = [[0, 0],[5617,3973]]; 
var image = L.imageOverlay('img/map.png', bounds).addTo(map); //the image to use as map
map.setView([2808,1987], -2);//Set the view port for the map
map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
```

However, when I take the co-ordinates at a certain point, it always returns the latlng with decimals e.g. (3667.66669,1200), (5454.66669,2500) and so on. I want it in such a way that latlng is a definite coordinate number with no decimal points at any zoom level e.g (2400,1121)

Comment: You might be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34484700/leaflet-latlngbounds-with-simpler-crs-projection/34510467#34510467 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37511237/how-do-switch-leaflet-coordinates-to-where-0-0-is-southwest/37517152#37517152